# If $b$ is the largest square divisor of $c$ and $a^2$ also divides $c$, then $a$ divides $b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, square-numbers

If $b$ is the largest square divisor of $c$ and $a^2$ also divides $c$, then $a$ divides $b$.

Assume $c = 72, b = 9, a = 2$.  Thus, $b$ would be the largest square divisor of $c$ and $a^2$ divides $c$, but $a$ doesn't divide $b$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange; no, $36$ is a square divisor of $72$ larger than $9$

Comment: You're mistaken because $36$ is a square divisor of $72$.  Square divisors don't have to be squares of primes.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig:  comma should go before the conjunction (*but*)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  I overlooked the last sentence while I was editing the title and adding the title to the body of the question.

Comment: $3^2$ is not be the *largest* square factor of $72$ because its cofactor $72/3^2 = 2\cdot 2^2$ also has a square factor, therefore $72$ has a larger square factor $\,3^2 2^2 = 6^2.\,$ This idea shows that the cofactor of the largest square factor must be squarefree (else we could increase its size as above).